# Why is that the Alexander polynomial cannot detect the chirality

Tags: knot-theory

In the knot theory lessons (and in wikipedia) it is stated that "The Alexander polynomial cannot detect the chirality", and it may be the case, but what worries me is that it is sometimes deduced right afted showing that $\Delta(K)=\Delta(K^*)$, where $K^*$ is the mirror image of the knot $K$.

But to my logic, it doesn't follow from this, because it can be another property of the Alexander polynomial, for example some structure of its roots or coefficients, that hypothetically can decide that if $\Delta$ has it then $K$ is chiral.

What should be the "proper" explenation of the statement "The Alexander polynomial cannot detect the chirality"?

Comment: See Theorem 2.4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04453.pdf).

Comment: Your question is unclear. The statement that two integer coefficient polynomials $\Delta_1(t,t^{-1})$ and $\Delta_2(t,t^{-1})$ are *equal* is equivalent to saying that their corresponding coefficients are equal. It follows from this that they have the same roots, and that any other property of these polynomials is identical. Perhaps you seem to have some other notion of *equality* in mind? If so, you should explain what that notion is.

Comment: I mean that it does not follow from the equality of the polynomials, when they are both equal to for example $t^{40}-1+t^{-40}$ maybe you can deduce that they must be chiral

Comment: More accurately, it should be "the Alexander polynomial does not distinguish a knot from its mirror image." That's a good point that the Alexander polynomial might contain information about whether a knot is chiral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consulted [KnotInfo](https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu/) to find pairs of knots with the same Alexander polynomial, one with a particular symmetry type and one chiral. An interpretation of the results is that the Alexander polynomial does not detect the symmetry type of a knot.

- The knot $8_9$ is fully amphicheiral, and it has the same Alexander polynomial as the chiral knot $11n_{37}$.
- The knot $12a_{341}$ is negative amphicheiral, and it has the same Alexander polynomial as the chiral knot $12a_{126}$.
- The knot $12a_{427}$ is positive amphicheiral, and it has the same Alexander polynomial as the chiral knot $12a_{189}$.
- The knot $5_2$ is reversible, and it has the same Alexander polynomial as the chiral knot $12n_{124}$.

That's not to say the Alexander polynomial contains no information about a knot's symmetry type.  As @plop references in the comments, [Theorem 2.4 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04453.pdf) has a condition that can sometimes exclude whether a knot is negative amphicheiral.  Recall that the Conway polynomial $\nabla_K(z)$ is related to the Alexander polynomial by $\nabla_K(t^2)=\Delta_K(t)$ (up to the usual factor of $\pm t^{n}$).  If $\nabla_K(z)$ can't factor as $f(z)f(-z)$ for some integer polynomial $f$, then $K$ is not negative amphicheiral (but given the data above, of a chiral knot with the same Alexander polynomial as a negative amphicheiral knot, the converse is not true).

---

The Jones polynomial has the property that $V(mL;t) = V(L;t^{-1})$, so amphicheiral knots have the same Jones polynomial. Let's do the same exercise for the Jones polynomial to see whether the Jones polynomial detects amphicheirality in general:

- $12a_{510}$ is fully amphicheiral, $12a_{821}$ is negative amphicheiral, and $12a_{1231}$ is chiral, but they all have the same Jones polynomial.
- $10_{33}$ is fully amphicheiral, $12n_{610}$ is reversible, and $12n_{278}$ is chiral, but they all have the same Jones polynomial.

It turns out there are no examples in the database of a positive amphicheiral knot with the same Jones polynomial as a chiral or reversible knot.

---

Regarding a comment by @knotter, here are the two mentioned knots:

14n14148:

[image: 14n14148]

14n14150:

[image: 14n14150]

I had hoped signature or omega signature might say one is not amphicheiral, but they are indistinguishable that way.  It does turn out you can distinguish them with their Alexander modules.  The second Alexander polynomial for the first knot is $1$, but for the second it is $2t^2-6t+2$.  I'm not sure what properties the higher Alexander polynomials have with respect to symmetry.  (I used https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/ to compute the Alexander module.  You can copy and paste the diagrams into this program to enter the knots.)

It seems interesting that these knots are Conway mutations of each other.  This is more obvious when 14n14148 is in this form:

[image: 11n14148]

The Conway mutation has the effect of taking the mirror image of the 6 crossings on the right half of the diagram.

Comment: A better question might be: why is it that Jones' polynomial can?

Comment: @user43408 I'd say that's just a different question, since they're not too related other than that they are both specializations of the HOMFLY-PT polynomial.  That said, I checked the database and it turned up examples where the Jones polynomial does not contain chirality information (answer updated).

Comment: Knots $14n_{14148}$ and  $14n_{14150}$ have the same the HOMFLY-PT polynomial, but exactly one of them is a positive amphicheiral knot (which one?).

Comment: @Knotter What table are you using? I only have the KnotInfo table on hand, but it could be interesting to try applying some other invariants (like signature) to figure out their symmetry types. (Or maybe it's possible to explicitly do the decomposition like in the Hartley paper mentioned in the sibling question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394946)

Comment: It is from the files at http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Take_Home_Database , it will be good to know which invariant tell them apart.

Comment: @Knotter The higher Alexander polynomials can tell them apart, but I'm not sure what that has to say about symmetry.